# React-native : Opening emoji keyboard

Tags: android, react-native, keyboard, emoji

I'm writing a small chat app in react-native, and I'm wondering if it's possible to open the keyboard as the default emoji phone keyboard (and switch to the regular text one easily).

For iPhone users, emojis are rather accessible, but on Android, it's not so easy to switch from a text keyboard to an emoji keyboard. I'd like to add to button near the text input to easily switch from one keyboard to another.

As I understand, it is not possible on iPhone, but is it on Android?

Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried? Please add more details.

Comment: Well not that much so far. I checked if there was a keyboardType =" emoji" or equivalent in inputText options. There is not, I looked over the web if there was a simple solution that does not involve installing a custom keyboard library and I coudln't find any so far...Thus I asked for help :-)

Answer (score -2):

Try This ,just install this dependency to use emoji keyboard directly,

[this](https://github.com/liangl1412/react-native-emoji-keyboard)

In this library, you will able to use many props related to emoji keyboard