# How can I open the emoji keyboard automatically? [react-native]

Tags: react-native, emoji

On most keyboards there is an emoji section:

[image: example]

I can open the keyboard by focusing onto a `<TextInput />` but this opens the keyboard with letters and numbers etc.

The `keyboardType` prop does not have anything similar to this emoji keyboard on it (as far as I know).

Is it possible to open the keyboard into the emojis section?

Thanks.

Comment: This question has been asked here https://stackoverflow.com/q/46725477/9161478
Without answer

Answer (score -3):

just install this dependency to use emoji keyboard directly,

https://github.com/liangl1412/react-native-emoji-keyboard

In this library, you will able to use many props related to emoji keyboard